# Nested for loop to replace cells in an array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have a masked image, and I'm trying to replace the masked pixels in that image with the values from another array. I'm using a nested for loop:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np  

#   Generate random image and mask
np.random.seed(seed=5)                      #   To use the same random numbers
h, w = 10, 10
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(h, w))    #   Generate a h x w array of 
                                            #   random integers from 0 - 1
img = np.random.rand(h, w)                  #   Generate a h x w array of 
                                            #   random floats
img_masked = np.where(mask, img, np.nan)    #   Mask the img array and replace
                                            #   invalid values with nan's

#   Use generic filter to compute nan-excluding median of masked image
size = 3
img_masked_median = ndi.generic_filter(img_masked, np.nanmedian, size=size)

new_img = np.ones_like(img_masked)
#   Use a for loop to look at each pixel in the masked, unfiltered image
height, width = img_masked.shape
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if img_masked[x, y] != []:
            new_img[x, y] = img[x, y]
        else:
            new_img[x, y] = img_masked_median[x, y]

#   Plot results in 4x4 grid
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
ax[0,0].imshow(img)
ax[0,0].set_title('img')
ax[0,1].imshow(img_masked_median)
ax[0,1].set_title('img_masked_median')
ax[1,0].imshow(img_masked)
ax[1,0].set_title('img_masked')
ax[1,1].imshow(new_img)
ax[1,1].set_title('new_img')
plt.show()
```

The filter works fine, now I just want to replace any masked pixels in img with the corresponding pixels from img_masked_median.
At the moment, the loop just produces a copy of img_masked_median. If I change the condition in line 24 to be

```
if img_masked[x, y] != np.nan:
```

now it produces a copy of img.
Why isn't the for loop replacing the pixels properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the initial version is that `img_masked[x, y]` will certainly never be `[]`, because that's the empty list - the elements of `img_masked` are numpy floats, not lists.

If you change the check to `if img_masked[x, y] != np.nan`, you run into the problem that `np.nan` does not equal itself:

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

The problem with both techniques is that the first `if` is always `True`, so you always use the old `img` to populate `new_img`. I highly recommend putting some `print`s in each branch when looking for bugs like this - it will make it clear that the branch is not working correctly.

To get consistent results, use `np.isnan`:

```
#   Use a for loop to look at each pixel in the masked, unfiltered image
height, width = img_masked.shape
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
        if np.isnan(img_masked[x, y]):
            new_img[x, y] = img[x, y]
        else:
            new_img[x, y] = img_masked_median[x, y]
```